# How do I pass a Structure that contains an array of Structures to a C++ function using JNA?

Tags: java, windows, struct, jna

I am building a Java application that communicates with a particular manufacturer's API using JNA. I have a ton of function calls mapped and already working, but there are a pair of functions that have been giving me some grief.

Both of these functions pass a data structure back and forth to configure the device. This structure has a nested array of data structures within it.

The native definitions:

```
VISION_API_DECL BOOL VISION_API SetDeviceParameters( DWORD DeviceID, DeviceParameters  DeviceParam );
VISION_API_DECL BOOL VISION_API GetDeviceParameters( DWORD DeviceID, DeviceParameters  *DeviceParam );
```

I have them declared in Java like so:

```
public interface Driver extends Library {
    ...
    public boolean SetDeviceParameters(int DeviceID, DEVICE_PARAMETERS DeviceParam);
    public boolean GetDeviceParameters(int DeviceID, DEVICE_PARAMETERS DeviceParam);
    ...
}
```

These function calls *seem* to work. JNA does not throw an exception when I call either of those functions. When I call the `GetDeviceParameters` method and print out the struct, I see most of it filled with data from what I would assume is the device's default configuration. However, when I call the `SetDeviceParameters` method using the *same data just returned from the get call*, the device returns an error saying the parameters are wrong.

**How do I know if I have mapped the structure correctly?**

Native:

```
typedef struct _DeviceParameters
{
  BOOL bMICREnable;
  UINT nMICRFont;
  BOOL bMICRSaveSamples;
  UINT nMICRSpaces;
  char cRejectSymbol;
  UINT nReserved;
  BOOL bReserved;
  IMAGE_PROPERTIES  ImagePropertiesFront1;
  IMAGE_PROPERTIES  ImagePropertiesFront2;
  IMAGE_PROPERTIES  ImagePropertiesRear1;
  IMAGE_PROPERTIES  ImagePropertiesRear2;
  SNIPPET_PROPERTIES SnippetProperties[10];
  BOOL bPrintEnable;
  BOOL bOneDoc;
  UINT nFeedingMode;
} DeviceParameters;

typedef struct _SnippetProperties
{
  BOOL Enable;
  BOOL Front;
  Snippet Properties;
} SNIPPET_PROPERTIES;

typedef struct _Snippet
{
  UINT Xposition;
  UINT Yposition;
  UINT Width;
  UINT Height;
  UINT Orientation;
  UINT Color;
  UINT Compression;
  BOOL Millimeters;
} Snippet;

typedef struct _ImageProperties
{
  UINT Format;
  UINT Paging;
  UINT Resolution;
  UINT ColorDepth;
  UINT Threshold;
} IMAGE_PROPERTIES;
```

Java:

```
public class DEVICE_PARAMETERS extends Structure {
    public boolean bMICREnable;
    public int nMICRFont;
    public boolean bMICRSaveSamples;
    public int nMICRSpaces;
    public byte cRejectSymbol;
    public int nReserved;
    public boolean bReserved;
    public IMAGE_PROPERTIES ImagePropertiesFront1;
    public IMAGE_PROPERTIES ImagePropertiesFront2;
    public IMAGE_PROPERTIES ImagePropertiesRear1;
    public IMAGE_PROPERTIES ImagePropertiesRear2;
    public SNIPPET_PROPERTIES[] SnippetProperties = new SNIPPET_PROPERTIES[10];
    public boolean bPrintEnable;
    public boolean bOneDoc;
    public int nFeedingMode;

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                "bMICREnable"
                , "nMICRFont"
                , "bMICRSaveSamples"
                , "nMICRSpaces"
                , "cRejectSymbol"
                , "nReserved"
                , "bReserved"
                , "ImagePropertiesFront1"
                , "ImagePropertiesFront2"
                , "ImagePropertiesRear1"
                , "ImagePropertiesRear2"
                , "SnippetProperties"
                , "bPrintEnable"
                , "bOneDoc"
                , "nFeedingMode"
        );
    }
}

public class IMAGE_PROPERTIES extends Structure {
    public int Format;
    public int Paging;
    public int Resolution;
    public int ColorDepth;
    public int Threshold;

    @SuppressWarnings("RedundantArrayCreation")
    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new String[]{
                        "Format"
                        , "Paging"
                        , "Resolution"
                        , "ColorDepth"
                        , "Threshold"
                }
        );
    }
}

public class SNIPPET_PROPERTIES extends Structure {
    public boolean Enable;
    public boolean Front;
    public SNIPPET Properties = new SNIPPET();

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("Enable", "Front", "Properties");
    }
}

public class SNIPPET extends Structure {

    public int Xposition;
    public int Yposition;
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
    public int Orientation;
    public int Color;
    public int Compression;
    public boolean Millimeters;

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("Xposition"
                , "Yposition"
                , "Width"
                , "Height"
                , "Orientation"
                , "Color"
                , "Compression"
                , "Millimeters"
        );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
DEVICE_PARAMETERS(auto-allocated@0x16a25938 (520 bytes)) {
  boolean bMICREnable@0=false
  int nMICRFont@4=1
  boolean bMICRSaveSamples@8=false
  int nMICRSpaces@c=2
  byte cRejectSymbol@10=3f
  int nReserved@14=0
  boolean bReserved@18=false
  IMAGE_PROPERTIES ImagePropertiesFront1@1c=IMAGE_PROPERTIES(allocated@0x16a25954 (20 bytes) (shared from auto-allocated@0x16a25938 (520 bytes))) {
    int Format@0=0
    int Paging@4=0
    int Resolution@8=0
    int ColorDepth@c=0
    int Threshold@10=0
  }
  IMAGE_PROPERTIES ImagePropertiesFront2@30=IMAGE_PROPERTIES(allocated@0x16a25968 (20 bytes) (shared from auto-allocated@0x16a25938 (520 bytes))) {
    int Format@0=0
    int Paging@4=0
    int Resolution@8=0
    int ColorDepth@c=0
    int Threshold@10=0
  }
  IMAGE_PROPERTIES ImagePropertiesRear1@44=IMAGE_PROPERTIES(allocated@0x16a2597c (20 bytes) (shared from auto-allocated@0x16a25938 (520 bytes))) {
    int Format@0=0
    int Paging@4=0
    int Resolution@8=0
    int ColorDepth@c=0
    int Threshold@10=0
  }
  IMAGE_PROPERTIES ImagePropertiesRear2@58=IMAGE_PROPERTIES(allocated@0x16a25990 (20 bytes) (shared from auto-allocated@0x16a25938 (520 bytes))) {
    int Format@0=0
    int Paging@4=0
    int Resolution@8=0
    int ColorDepth@c=0
    int Threshold@10=0
  }
  SNIPPET_PROPERTIES SnippetProperties[10]@6c=[Lpanini.data.SNIPPET_PROPERTIES;@fb642f
  boolean bPrintEnable@1fc=false
  boolean bOneDoc@200=false
  int nFeedingMode@204=1
}
memory dump
[00000000]
[01000000]
[00000000]
[02000000]
[3f000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[01000000]
Device Error: Wrong device parameters <-- this is where I try to set params
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't included your method declarations, which should look like this (assuming you haven't simply made a typo in the declaration):

```
boolean SetDeviceParameters(int deviceID, DeviceParameters.ByValue params);
boolean GetDeviceParameters(int deviceID, DeviceParameters params);
```

Make sure that you use a version of the structure tagged with `Structure.ByValue` when passing to the `SetDeviceParameters()` method.  You'll need to define a `ByValue` version of your structure.

```
public class DeviceParameters extends Structure {
    public ByValue extends DeviceParameters implements Structure.ByValue {
        public ByValue() { }
        public ByValue(Pointer p) { super(p); read(); }
    }
}
```

You can then convert from `struct *` to `struct` like this:

```
DeviceParameters dp = new DeviceParameters();
DeviceParameters.ByValue bv = new DeviceParameters.ByValue(dp.getPointer());
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the Java mapping, and it indeed looks like I did not map things correctly. Your answer makes a lot of sense, and once properly mapped the call succeeded. Thanks for the help.