# Unable to pass a structure with single byte array field to native code via JNA

Tags: java, jna

I am successfully able to get this structure with a single byte array field as output as part  of another bigger structure. However, when I pass this same structure as an input argument, the native code is unable to decipher the data in the byte array. I have verified that the native code is able to successfully handle the call on direct invocation without JNA in the picture. I need to know, what is the problem with the structure definition in Java which could be causing this problem.

**Details**
I am using a third party library which has the following C structure for a GUID:

```
typedef struct GuidType
{
    uint8_t data[16];
}  GuidType;
```

GuidType gets used in other bigger structures and is a common identity information that is used to perform various kinds of data manipulation. For example,

```
typedef struct DataObjectType1 {
   GuidType guid;
   const char * detail1;
   // various other fields
} DataObjectType1;

typedef struct DataObjectType1Array {
   size_t size;
   DataObjectType1 ** data; // array of pointers. Each pointer points to a structure
} 

typedef struct DataObjectType2 {
   GuidType guid;
   const char * detail2;
   // various other fields
} DataObjectType2;
```

The third party library has APIs on the following lines:

```
int getAllDataObjectType1Instances(DataObjectType1Array ** dataObjectType1Instances);
int getDataObjectType2ForGuid(GuidType guid, DataObjectType2 ** dataObjectType2);
```

After reading the JNA documentation and using Jnaerator, I could come up with the following Java-JNA code:

```
GuidType extends Structure {
  public byte[] data = new byte[16];

  public GuidType(Pointer p){
    super(p);
    read();
  }

  public GuidType() { }
}

DataObjectType1 extends Structure {
  public GuidType guid;
  public String detail1;
  // various other fields
  
  // Default constructor and constructor with pointer as argument
}

DataObjectType1Array extends Structure {
   public int size;
   public Pointer data;

  // Default constructor and constructor with pointer as argument
}


DataObjectType2 extends Structure {
  public GuidType guid;
  public String detail2;
  // various other fields

  // Default constructor and constructor with pointer as argument
}

// Native API equivalent in Java using JNA 
int getAllDataObjectType1Instances(PointerByReference dataObjectType1Instances);
int getDataObjectType2ForGuid(GuidType guid, PointerByReference dataObjectType2Instance);
```

With the above code, I am able to successfully invoke the getAllDataObjectType1Instances API which returns all the DataObjectType1 instances and has all the fields correctly initialized in the structure. However, the getDataObjectType2ForGuid call always fails. The code is on the following lines:

```
PointerByReference dataObjectType1Instances = new PointerByReference();
int result = libraryInstance.getAllDataObjectType1Instances(dataObjectType1Instances);
if(result == 0){
    DataObjectType1Array dataObjectType1Array = new DataObjectType1Array(dataObjectType1Instances.getValue());
    Pointer[] pointers = dataObjectType1Array.data.getPointerArray(0, dataObjectType1Array.size);
    for(Pointer pointer : pointers){
       DataObjectType1 dataObjectType1 = new DataObjectType1(pointer);
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dataObjectType1.guid.data)); // this shows the correct GUID details
 
      // More print statements that indicate other fields in dataObjectType1 are also initialized correctly.


       PointerByReference dataObjectType2PointerByReference = new PointerByReference(); 
       
       result = libraryInstance.getDataObjectType2ForGuid(dataObjectType1.guid, dataObjectType2PointerByReference); // this always fails. On success, library assigns the address of a DataObjectType2 pointer to dataObjectType2PointerByReference.
 
      // ... Code to extract DataObjectType2 instance from dataObjectType2Reference.
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, the libraryInstance.getDataObjectType2ForGuid() call fails with an error that indicates that actual data is not getting passed to the native code. I have also tried creating a new GuidType instance with the right data in the byte array field and then passing it to getDataObjectType2ForGuid(), but with no success.

I am unable to identify what is going wrong here? Can someone help. Let me know, if more details are needed or something is not clear. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** Not sure if it matters, but the native library is written in  C++. So we are dealing with a C++ struct here.

Comment: Should you have a call to `super()` in your no-arg constructor for `GuidType`?

Comment: Have tried `public GuidType() { super(); }` just now. But it does not seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419936/12665631), I could resolve the issue by passing `GuidType.ByValue` to `getDataObjectType2ForGuid`. Changes in the code are as follows:

```
class GuidType extends Structure {
   public static class ByValue extends GuidType implements Structure.ByValue {
        public ByValue() { }

        public ByValue(Pointer p){ super(p); read(); }
   }

   // ... other existing code
}
//  Change in signature of getDataObjectType2ForGuid to use GuideType.ByValue
int getDataObjectType2ForGuid(GuidType.ByValue guid, DataObjectType2 ** dataObjectType2);

// Code to invoke getDataObjectType2ForGuid()
result = libraryInstance.getDataObjectType2ForGuid(
             new GuidType.ByValue(dataObjectType1.guid.getPointer()), 
             dataObjectType2PointerByReference);
```

Thanks @Daniel Widdis for all the support.

Comment: Ah, I see it now, the `GuidType` argument in the method call did not have the `*` indicating pointer, so the `ByValue` fix is correct. Sorry I missed that on the first go around.  Obviously without the API I wasn't sure about the other argument.

Answer (score 1):

I originally answered suggesting you needed to allocate memory for the structure pointed to by the `PointerByReference`.  That turned out to be the wrong suggestion, because, as you later indicated, the API told you it would allocate its own memory and return a pointer to it.

As you've observed, you hit an unusual situation where a C library expects a struct to be passed by value.  The key clue is in this method signature:

```c
int getDataObjectType2ForGuid(GuidType guid, PointerByReference dataObjectType2Instance);
```

JNA by default treats structures `ByValue` when declared inside other structures (such as how it is defined in `DataObjectType2`) and `ByReference` when passed in method arguments (which usually have the `*` indicating a pointer -- you'd have seen `GuidType *guid`).

In the case where the native api differs from this default convention (either the pointer-based variant in a structure, or the full structure in a method call) you need to explicitly tag the structures `ByValue` or `ByReference`.

This is discussed in the [JNA Overview](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.8.0/javadoc/overview-summary.html#overview_description) under the "Structures" heading.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. However, that did not solve the problem. I get the same error.

Comment: @AnandNavale Can you be more specific on the error code or what "fails" means?  With the updated code you still haven't changed any values in `dot2` that you're trying to pass to native, so it's a block of blank memory.

Comment: The error is `*** trace: [2] E GuardBoundary.hpp:60 GuardBoundary context: getDataObjectType2ForGuid [0x2100584] Location: '/Users/runner/work/1/s/src/oem/lib/module/Class.cpp[68] GetItem' Exception Text: Id not found: '13289059'`. So, it is very specific to this proprietary library which is from another vendor. So far no one has tried integrating their library with a Java application which is something I am working on.

Comment: Regarding `dot2` initialization. This particular native library, actually expects an uninitialized `DataObjectType2 ** dataObjectType2`. On further investigation, I found that the `getDataObjectType2ForGuid` call internally allocates memory to a pointer and sets the address of that pointer to the input argument `dataObjectType2`. I think the variable should have been named better to indicate that. Therefore, the original code that I had written to pass uninitialized `PointerByReference` seems appropriate.

Comment: One more thing to add here - the library has additional APIs to free the internally allocated memory, which need to be invoked by the calling code. Here again, I pass the same `PointerByReference` which is initialized by `getDataObjectType2ForGuid `.

Comment: I see in your answer how you fixed this.  Glad you were able to solve it.